# Prove $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{xy} ~dxdy}{(x+y)(1+x y)^s}=\frac{\pi}{2(s-1)}$ for $s>1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

By evaluation with WolframAlpha for different values of $s$ it is apparent that:

> $$I(s)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{xy} ~dxdy}{(x+y)(1+x y)^s}=\frac{\pi}{2(s-1)},~~~~~s>1$$

I'm not really familiar with this kind of integrals. Can we introduce new coordinates like:

$$u=xy,~~~~~v=x+y$$

But then the expressions for $x(u,v)$ and $y(u,v)$ become conditional on $x>y$ or $x<y$, so I'm not sure how to transform the integral correctly.

We can also try something like this to build a recurrence:

$$I(s)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{xy ~dxdy}{\sqrt{xy}(x+y)(1+x y)^s}= \\ =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{xy}(x+y)(1+x y)^{s-1}}-\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{xy}(x+y)(1+x y)^{s}}$$

But this doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Is this a Mellin transform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By symmetry the integral over $y\geq x$ equals the integral over $y\leq x$, hence:

$$ I(s) = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{(x+y)(1+xy)^s}\,dy\,dx= 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x z^2}{(1+z^2)(1+x^2 z^2)^s}\,dz\,dx $$
through the substitution $y=x z^2$. The substitution $x=\frac{t}{z}$ and Fubini's theorem then lead to:
$$ I(s) = 4\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t}{(1+z^2)(1+t^2)^s}\,dz\,dt =\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t\,dt}{(1+t^2)^s}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2(s-1)}}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Your first line was most helpful!

Comment: @YuriyS: symmetry tricks are often *very* powerful :)

Comment: Jack, apology for the "incorrect" edit.  I've reversed it to the original.  And +1

Answer (score 6):

If you let $u=xy$ and $v=y/x$ you get
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+u)^s}\,du\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{v}(1+v)}\,dv
$$
which is easy to integrate.

Comment: This is even better. Should've tried this substitution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to transform coordinates to polar coordinates.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
I(s)&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)}}{\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi)}\left(\int_0^\infty \frac{r}{\left(1+r^2\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)\right)^s}\,dr\right)\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2(s-1)}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(\phi)\cos(\phi)}(\sin(\phi)+\cos(\phi))}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2(s-1)}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(2(\phi-\pi/4))}\,\cos(\phi-\pi/4)} \,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2(s-1)}\,2\,\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(2\phi)}\,\cos(\phi)} \,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(s-1)}\,\left.\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\sin(\phi)}{\sqrt{\cos(2\phi)}}\right)\right)\right|_{0}^{\pi/4}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2(s-1)}
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Nice job @Dr.MV. Maybe later you can help me on a double integral.

Comment: @Chinacat Thank you!  And I'd be happy to help if I can.